# How can I load my partial view using ajax call?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I’m trying to load a partial view with an ajax call.  I’m trying to follow a solution I found here:  [Render partial view onclick in asp.net mvc 3 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624224/render-partial-view-onclick-in-asp-net-mvc-3-project)

My script looks like this:

```
 $("#174").on("click", function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/TeacherStudent/StudentInformation",

            data: "174",
            datatype: "html",
            sucess: function (data) {
             $("#theTimes").html(result);

            }
        });
    });
```

My controller looks like this:

```
  public ActionResult StudentInformation(string data)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(data);


        var viewModel = new ScheduleData();

        var attend = from s in db.Assignments where s.teacherId == 7 && s.StudentId == 174 select s;
        var enroll = from s in db.Enrollments where s.InstructorId == 7 && s.StudentID == 174 select s;
        var stdParent = from s in db.Parents select s;

        viewModel.Assignments = attend;
        viewModel.Enrollments = enroll;
        viewModel.Parents = stdParent;
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/StudentInformation.cshtml");
         }

     }
```

Somewhere in my view I have div tag:

```
 <div id="theTimes"></div>
```

I confirmed that the program calls the partial view but the view does not get displayed in the div tag. What could I be missing in the ajax call?  Thanks for helping out!

Comment: just change the result to data... because you have not defined the result parameter in your ajax.

Comment: try this:
return View("~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/StudentInformation.cshtml");

Comment: @Azim Returning an entire view would also render the `_Layout` - a bad idea for filling in only a part of a page.

Answer (score 3):

The problem looks like it's on this line.

```
sucess: function (data) {
    $("#theTimes").html(result);
}
```

`result` is undefined and 'sucess' isn't a valid callback.

Try this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#theTimes").html(data);
}
```

Also, change `datatype` to `dataType` (grammar) and change `data: "174"` to `data: {"data": "174"}`.

I.e.

```
$("#174").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/TeacherStudent/StudentInformation",
        data: {"data": "174"},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
         $("#theTimes").html(data);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I've tried .html(data) also.  Both ways the view is called ok but not rendered.

Comment: Check spelling, as indicated by `Stuy1974`.

Comment: I checked the spelling all is correct.  I noticed that in the controller, data is null so I think the syntax of the ajax call is maybe missing something.

Comment: I've appended a sentence to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Rowan, it did get the data to the controller but the partial view is still not loading.

Comment: OK after changing the order of the unobtrusive script references I get the view but it does not load in the div tag...it loads in a separate page.  Any ideas?